# Consulta SQLITE retornando valor fora da regra de consulta

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Fiz um programa, em linguagem python, que cria um banco de dados **SQLITE** que armazena informações sobre uma quantidade de portas de uma armário. As informações armazenadas são: id (identificação da porta), tamanho (PQ = pequeno, MD = médio, GD = grande), habilitado (true/false), ocupado (true/false), qtd_ciclos (quantidade de vzs de uso da porta). Segue abaixo o código:

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\db\teste_sqlite_db.sqlite')
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise

    def init_tables(self):
        try:
            # Cria tabela das portas
            self.conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS porta(
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                tamanho VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                                habilitado BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                                ocupado BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                                qtd_ciclos INTEGER NOT NULL
                                )''')
            self.conn.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise
        finally:
            self.conn.rollback()

    def close(self):
        try:
            self.conn.close()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise

    def insert_porta(self, id: int, tamanho: str, habilitado: bool, ocupado: bool, qtd_cliclos: int):
        ret = 0

        try:
            self.conn.execute('INSERT INTO porta(id, tamanho, habilitado, ocupado, qtd_ciclos) '
                          'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (str(id), tamanho, str(habilitado), str(ocupado),
                                                     str(qtd_cliclos)))
            self.conn.commit()
            ret = 1
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise
        finally:
            self.conn.rollback()
        return ret

    def select_porta_com_menor_qtd_ciclos(self, tamanho: str, habilitado: bool, ocupado: bool):
        try:
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM porta WHERE qtd_ciclos = (SELECT MIN(qtd_ciclos) FROM porta WHERE tamanho='{}' AND "
            "habilitado='{}' AND ocupado='{}');".format(tamanho, habilitado, ocupado))

            rows = cur.fetchall()

            print("========================")
            for row in rows:
                print("ID: {}".format(row[0]))
                print("TAMANHO: {}".format(row[1]))
                print("HABILITADO: {}".format(row[2]))
                print("OCUPADO: {}".format(row[3]))
                print("QTD_CICLOS: {}".format(row[4]))

            cur.close()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(str(e))
            raise
        return rows


def main():
    database = Database()
    database.init_tables()
    database.insert_porta(1, 'PQ', True, False, 10)
    database.insert_porta(2, 'PQ', True, False, 9)
    database.insert_porta(3, 'MD', True, False, 8)
    database.insert_porta(4, 'MD', True, False, 15)
    database.insert_porta(5, 'GD', True, True, 2)
    database.insert_porta(6, 'MD', True, False, 5)
    database.insert_porta(7, 'PQ', False, False, 8)
    database.insert_porta(8, 'MD', True, False, 5)
    database.insert_porta(9, 'GD', True, False, 7)
    database.insert_porta(10, 'MD', True, False, 7)

    database.select_porta_com_menor_qtd_ciclos('PQ', True, False)
    print("===========================================================")
    database.select_porta_com_menor_qtd_ciclos('MD', True, False)
    print("===========================================================")
    database.select_porta_com_menor_qtd_ciclos('GD', True, False)

    database.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As regras da consulta dos registros das portas é: Retorna do banco a(s) porta(s) com menor uso (qtd_ciclos), sendo que, ela tenha determinado tamanho (PQ, MD ou GD), esteja habilitada (habilitado = true) e desocupada (ocupado = false). 
Conforme pode-se verificar no método `def select_porta_com_menor_qtd_ciclos(self, tamanho: str, habilitado: bool, ocupado: bool)` a query de consulta ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM porta WHERE qtd_ciclos = (SELECT MIN(qtd_ciclos) FROM porta WHERE tamanho='{}' AND habilitado='{}' AND ocupado='{}');".format(tamanho, habilitado, ocupado))
```

Eu criei a seguinte tabela para testar a consulta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>Exported table: porta</title><style type="text/css">table{border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-collapse:collapse;}table tr{background-color:white;}table tr.header{background-color:#DDDDDD;}table tr.title{background-color:#EEEEEE;}table tr td{padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#666666;}table tr td.null{color:#999999;text-align:center;padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#666666;}table tr td.separator{padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#666666;background-color:#DDDDDD;}table tr td.rownum{padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#666666;background-color:#DDDDDD;text-align:right;}</style><body><table><tr class="title"><td colspan="6" align="center">Table: porta</td></tr><tr class="header"><td align="right"><b><i>#</i></b></td><td><b>id</b><br/>INTEGER</td><td><b>tamanho</b><br/>VARCHAR</td><td><b>habilitado</b><br/>BOOLEAN</td><td><b>ocupado</b><br/>BOOLEAN</td><td><b>qtd_ciclos</b><br/>INTEGER</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>1</i></td><td align="right">1</td><td align="left">PQ</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">10</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>2</i></td><td align="right">2</td><td align="left">PQ</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">9</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>3</i></td><td align="right">3</td><td align="left">MD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">8</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>4</i></td><td align="right">4</td><td align="left">MD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">15</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>5</i></td><td align="right">5</td><td align="left">GD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="right">2</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>6</i></td><td align="right">6</td><td align="left">MD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">5</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>7</i></td><td align="right">7</td><td align="left">PQ</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">8</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>8</i></td><td align="right">8</td><td align="left">MD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">5</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>9</i></td><td align="right">9</td><td align="left">GD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">7</td></tr><tr><td class="rownum"><i>10</i></td><td align="right">10</td><td align="left">MD</td><td align="left">True</td><td align="left">False</td><td align="right">7</td></tr></table><br/><br/><i>Document generated by SQLiteStudio v3.1.1 on qua mai 8 10:20:34 2019</i></body></html>
```

- Ao fazer o teste, quando procuro pelas portas PQ (pequena) a consulta retorna corretamente as portas de ID 9 e 10, ambas possuem mesma quantidade de ciclos (7). (Verifique na tabela);
- Quando procuro pelas portas MD (média) a consulta retorna corretamente as portas de ID 6 e 8, ambas possuem mesma quantidade de ciclos (5). (Verifique na tabela);
- Porém, quando procuro pelas portas GD (grade) a consulta retorna erradamente. Era para retornar apenas a porta com ID 9 com 7 ciclos, porém, além da porta com ID 9, a consulta também retorna a porta com ID 10 que é uma porta de tamanho MD (média), mas coincidentemente com 7 cilcos também. (Verifique na tabela);

Alguém saberia me dizer porque a consulta pela porta GD (grande) se comporta dessa maneira? Não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema.

Comment: Poderia elaborar um [mcve] do problema? Há muito ruído na pergunta. Se o problema é que a consulta está retornando dados errados, basta colocar na pergunta a consulta que fez, junto com os dados que estão na tabela, descrevendo qual foi o resultado e qual era o esperado. Parece-me que todo esse código em Python e HTML não tem relação alguma com o problema.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o próprio código é um exemplo verificável, ele possui uma main que cria o banco, insere os registros exatamente de acordo com a tabela e faz as consultas que citei: Consulta portas PQ (pequena), consulta portas MD (media) e portas GD (grande). Basta copiar o código e rodar o arquivo.

Comment: Eu vou adicionar como eu fiz as consultas ao banco na descrição do problema.

Comment: Isso seria um bom [mcve]: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2dnNjmidkABv2RMXNejTz/0. Você tem a tabela, tem os dados e tem a consulta. Tudo o que você precisa na sua pergunta. É só descrever porque o resultado que obteve não era o resultado esperado. Não precisa ter Python e HTML no meio.

Comment: Eu agradeço pela observação, mas creio ter feito de acordo com o tutorial que você linckou. O código está o mais simples possível com relação ao código real. Ele reproduz o cenário necessário para o erro e o mesmo é gerado. A tabela visual é a tabela que o código cria no banco e que gerará o erro. Resumindo, o código cria o banco, insere as informações exatamente conforme a tabela, faz as consultas citadas na explicação e gera o erro sem precisar editá-lo, talvez, somente editar o diretório do banco. Mas levarei sua crítica em consideração e tentar melhorar minhas próximas perguntas. Obrigado.

Comment: Sim e isso já é de grande ajuda. A questão que eu quis levantar é que mesmo dando para reproduzir o problema você consegue eliminar bastante coisa que é ruído e simplificar bastante a sua pergunta.

Comment: Entendi! Creio que preciso melhorar nisso, mesmo. Vou me atentar mais a isso. Valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de lógica que você tem não é do Python, e sim do SQL  - 
a sua consulta é:

```
SELECT * FROM porta WHERE qtd_ciclos = 
    (SELECT MIN(qtd_ciclos) FROM porta WHERE 
          tamanho='{}' AND habilitado='{}' AND ocupado='{}'
     )
```

Ou seja - o select de fora só tem *uma* condição de where, que é a "qtd_ciclos". O select interno sim, tem a constraint de tamanho da porta, e habilitado, e ocupado - mas retorna apenas um númrero (no caso do seu exemplo, 7) - e a consulta externa então retorna todas as portas com aquele número de ciclos, independente de tamanho, "habilitado" ou "ocupado".

As soluções óbvias são ou colocar as 3 condições também no select de fora, ou criar um único select, e ordenar a query pela ordem decrescente da qtd_ciclos - os primeiros resultados serão os menores ciclos, e você filtra do lado do Python os valores iguais.

Dito isso - algo importantíssimo no quesito segurança - apesar do Python ter diversas maneiras de formartar strings, ao usar queries SQL - seja sqlite, ou qualquer outro conector, é importante deixar o *driver* de sql posicionar os parâmetros, e não usar o método `.format` ou outra forma de formatar a string - isso evita que parâmetros maliciosos possam ser usados para SQL injection.

Aqui vai como pode ficar a chamada ao cursor.execut para os dois estilos.
(outra coisa é que apesar de algumas regras de estilo recomendarem o uso de
`"` em todas as linhas de strings longas, como o seu SQL, e contar com a concatenação do compilado, é muito mais conveniente usar as strings com aspas triplas - `"""` -  e colocar toda a query numa única string - isso evita dificuldade de digitação na query, dificuldade na leitura, possíveis problemas
por esquecer ou sobrar uma `"` em algum lugar, entre outras coisas.  Nunca deixe as "normas de estilo" atrapalharem em vez de ajudarem.

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM porta WHERE 
        tamanho=:tamanho AND 
        habilitado=:habilitado AND
        tamanho=:tamanho AND
        qtd_ciclos= (SELECT MIN(qtd_ciclos) FROM porta WHERE 
              tamanho=:tamanho AND
              habilitado=:habilitado AND
              ocupado=:ocupado
         )
    """, 
   {"tamanho": tamanho, "habilitado": habilitado, "ocupado": ocupado}
)
```

Usando a notação de "named parameters" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor ), você passa um dicionário com chaves:valores no segundo parâmetro do execute - e deixa o Python pegar os valores, converter para SQL (valores numéricos, booleanos e datas são convertidos automaticamente para a notação do SQL, por exemplo, sem nunca ser necessário uma conversão explícita do tipo `str(...)` - além de se evitar qualquer ataque de SQL injection - e, nesse caso, de se passar cada parâmetro uma vez só, mesmo que sejam usdos duas vezes na query. (Parâmetros puramente posicionais - seja como você estava usando o "format", seja com a notação de `?` do SQLite 
são propensos a erro na ordenação, e de difícil verificação ao se fazer o review do código).

(observe também que o `;` final do statement de SQL não deve ser usado - ele é uma sintaxe do uso interativo do SQL, não dos comandos Select - O sqlite o ignora, mas há drivers de banco de dados em que a inclusão do  `;` é um erro de sintaxe)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pela aula. Sou novo tanto em python quanto em SQLITE. Sua explicação ajudou bastante e agregou conhecimento. Valeu!